# Adding resize handles to a node

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element I would like to show resize handles on. My current code:

```
const cursorMove = (e) => {
    if (!curData.doAnimate) {

        mouse.x = e.clientX;
        mouse.y = e.clientY;

        resize = {
            top: mouse.y < curPos.y + settings.resizeMargin,
            right: mouse.x > curPos.x + curPos.w - settings.resizeMargin,
            bottom: mouse.y > curPos.y + curPos.h - settings.resizeMargin,
            left: mouse.x < curPos.x + settings.resizeMargin,
        };
        const {top, right, bottom, left} = resize;

        if (top || left || right || bottom) {
            // mouse over border

            if ((top && left) || (bottom && right)) {
                wrap.style.cursor = 'nwse-resize';
            } else if ((top && right) || (bottom && left)) {
                wrap.style.cursor = 'nesw-resize';
            } else if (top || bottom) {
                wrap.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
            } else if (left || right) {
                wrap.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
            }
        } else {
            wrap.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
    }
};

wrap.addEventListener('mousemove', cursorMove);
```

as you can see I use javascript to add an eventlistener for mouse movments, and every time the mouse moves I check weather it is on a border of the element. I can turn the eventlistener off if I do something with the node using curData.doAnimate. I could remove the eventlistener if I move out of the element, but I dont think this would improve the performence.

Ideal would be a solution using Css or a solution without an eventlistener permanently listening to move events.

Thank you in advance :)

Edit: I am only interested in the changed cursor - I already have a function to resize the node (unless you know a super slick way of doing so using some magic).

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, CSS already has a property for handling this: [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: Sadly this does not resolve my problem, It only adds a resize handle to the bottom right corner and  doesent change the cursor (which is the main point, I guess i should have clarified this). I also already have a function which resizes the node. But thank you anyway :)